# Specify Python location in cgi script

Tags: python, cgi

I am writing a cgi script to run on a server, and when I put `#!/bin/python3` at the top of the file it works fine. The problem is that on my local machine, my Python installation is in `/opt/local/bin/python` (and macOS does not allow symlinks in `/bin`. So to run the script on my local machine, I need to manually change the path in each `cgi` file, which is cumbersome.

Is there a better way to specify my Python path (something like "try this path first else try this path?")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let your system environment choose the path using `#!/usr/bin/env python3`